# Do merge --squash create conflicts in Git flow?

Tags: git

**Context** : My team is following a standard Git flow, with branches `release` and `develop` and we have recurring conflicts problems when merging `release` into `develop`. I suspect a problem coming from the merge strategy.

Here is a scenario :
The initial situation is a file named `hello.txt` containing only `1,2,3`. The sequence is :

1. Create a PR from `release` in order to add a line `4, 5, 6` **and merge it**
2. Create a PR from `develop` to report this commit **and merge it**
3. Create a PR from `develop` in order to add a line `7, 8, 9` **and merge it**
4. Create a PR from `develop` in order to merge `release` into `develop`

Depending on the merge strategy, there is a conflict. To my understanding, Git should "see" (but I don't understand how it works) that the "`4, 5, 6`" commit from `release` has already been reported to `develop`. Somehow, it seems that it is not always the case when merging PRs with `git merge --squash`.

Here are the results I get :

- With a simple `git merge` strategy, everything is fine
- With `git merge --squash && git commit --no-edit`, there are no conflicts but the commit messages are messy in the logs
- With `git merge --squash && git commit -m "Report --- into ---"`, there is a conflict

**Questions** : Am I doing something wrong with the way I report commits (see below) ? Or is `merge --squash` not recommended when using Git flow ? Also, how does git identifies commits to be merged ? Why just changing the commit messages affects it ?

Here is a shell script which creates a temporary git repo and does the previously mentioned git operations. It is intended to mimic PR creation/merge as performed by BitBucket with the merge strategy used in my team. Please take a look at the function called `merge` as it allows to change the merge strategy.

**CAUTION** : never execute a shell script if you do not fully understand what it does.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

function log_step() {
  echo -e "\n\e[96m${*}\e[0m"
}

# Delegates the call to the merge strategy and passing args
# You can uncomment the desired strategy
function merge()
{
#  merge_simple $*
  merge_squash_rename $*
#  merge_squash_no_edit $*
}

function merge_squash_rename(){
  echo -e "\e[94mMerge ${1} into ${2}\e[0m"
  git checkout ${2}
  git merge --squash ${1}
  git commit -m "Merge ${1} into ${2}"
}

function merge_squash_no_edit(){
  echo -e "\e[94mMerge ${1} into ${2}\e[0m"
  git checkout ${2}
  git merge --squash ${1}
  git commit --no-edit
}

function merge_simple(){
  echo -e "\e[94mMerge ${1} into ${2}\e[0m"
  git checkout ${2}
  git merge ${1}
}

tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d -t strategit-XXXXXXXX)

echo "Created directory ${tmp_dir}"
cd ${tmp_dir}

# Initial state : a file named hello.txt, containing "1,2,3"
log_step "Create initial file with 1,2,3"
git init
echo '1,2,3' >> hello.txt
git add hello.txt
git commit -m 'First commit'

# Create initial branches release + develop
log_step "Create branches release and develop"
git checkout -b release
git checkout -b develop

# Work on ticket FW-456 on release
log_step "Create PR on release in order to add the line 4,5,6"
git checkout release
git checkout -b feature/FW-456
echo '4,5,6' >> hello.txt
git add hello.txt
git commit -m 'feature/FW-456'
# Keep it for cherry-pick later
ORIGINAL_COMMIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

log_step "Merge the PR on release"
merge feature/FW-456 release

# report PR on develop by creating a report branch
log_step "Create the report branch from develop"
git checkout develop
git checkout -b report/feature/FW-456
git cherry-pick ${ORIGINAL_COMMIT_HASH}

log_step "Merge the report branch on develop"
merge report/feature/FW-456 develop

# Work on ticket FW-789 on develop
log_step "Create a new PR from develop to add the line 7,8,9"
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/FW-789
echo '7,8,9' >> hello.txt
git add hello.txt
git commit -m 'feature/FW-789'

log_step "Merge the PR in develop"
merge feature/FW-789 develop

# Now, report release into develop
log_step "Create a PR on develop to report release in develop"
git checkout develop
git checkout -b chore/report-release-into-develop
# "|| true" to prevent script from exiting because of the potential conflict error

log_step "Try to merge"
git merge release || true

echo ""
echo "***************************************************"
echo "*                                                 *"
echo -e "* See result in directory \e[92m${tmp_dir}\e[0m *"
echo "*                                                 *"
echo "***************************************************"
```

Comment: `git merge --squash` will not actually create a merge commit, are you sure that this is what you want? I don't think this should be done in Git-flow.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I agree but "squash" is an available merge strategy in BitBucket. I thought it would not be the case if it was so dangerous

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle it’s not dangerous per se just not in line with git-flow’s strategy